# Linear algebra - minimal distance

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on this linear algebra problem: [image]

I know that the minimal distance from a vector $v$ to a subspace $U$ (i.e., the smallest value of $||v-u||$) is $||v - P_u(v)||$, but I can't relate that to this problem. Specifically, I don't know how I can incorporate $p(0)^2$ into the integral.

Any hint or solution is appreciated. Thanks!

Update: I solved this problem by finding the global minimum of a bivariate polynomial. But since this is a linear algebra problem I am wondering whether there is a linear algebra approach to it.

Comment: $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, $-a+b-c+d=0$, $3a-2b+c=0$, $p(0)=d$, $(1-5x-p'(x))^2=\dots$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did end up using the vector calculus method to do it, namely finding the global minimum of a multivariable polynomial since $p$ is generated by $(x+1)^2$. But I feel that there is a linear algebra way to approach this problem.